# Connect is not a function (Mongoose / MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to a database using MongoDB.  I am getting the following error message when I reload the page:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMJzh.png) however, when I check the console log, it shows
"Connected to DB", so I know it's connecting (I think), but why is it showing the error message when I reload the page? [Connected Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnY8W.png).  I am trying to use NodeJS, React, Mongoose, and MongoDB.

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import mongoose from "mongoose";


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/profile', {useNewUrlParser: true, 
useUnifiedTopology:true})
.then (() => {
  console.log("Connected to DB")
})
.catch (err => {
console.log("not connected")
console.log(err)
})

const AboutPage = () => {
return (
  <Layout>
    <h2>
            About Jake Hollcroft:
    </h2>

        
  </Layout>
  )
 }

export default AboutPage
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to connect directly from frontend. Maybe you should run a backend server (Eg: Express) and have that process connect to mongoose.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!!